# How much do extensions generally increase loading times by? If an extension works on video players, how much will it increase buffering by?

Tags: html5-video, browser-extension

If you have information regarding common browser extensions, feel free to share! If I were to have an extension that inspected a video element, perhaps the file itself and its contents, how much do you think that would delay buffering by (is there a way to do this efficiently you'd recommend?). Noob here, but I'm gonna get the gist of it I'm sure!

Comment: Depends completely on what and how.

Comment: True, I'll get back to you on that soon I'm sure =P